# SQLDF Left Join still deleting rows from Table A

Tags: sql, database, r, sqldf

I apologize if this has been answered on here already, but I can't find anything about my specific problem.

I have a time-series of years and months, and time-series data of biomass for many species.  I need to separate out time series for fifteen specific species.  Unfortunately, if no individuals of a species were encountered in a given month, no data was entered, leaving gaps in my time series where there should be 0's.  To remedy this, I'm trying to left join the species data (right hand table) onto a complete time series (left hand table).  Unfortunately, my output join is still missing the months without data.  For example, I'm missing 1986 month 1, because there is no data from my right hand table for that month.  I thought a left join was supposed to include those rows, but leave the right-hand columns blank.

I've got my code below.  Anything you can suggest would be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
Species1<-sqldf("SELECT TimeSeries.StartYear, TimeSeries.StartMonthNo, CommonName, EstimatedBiomassg, ScaledProportionofDominantNektonBiomass
            FROM TimeSeries 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN TrawlBiomassbyMonth 
            ON TimeSeries.StartYear = TrawlBiomassbyMonth.StartYear 
            AND TimeSeries.StartMonthNo = TrawlBiomassbyMonth.StartMonthNo 
            WHERE CommonName = 'White shrimp'
            AND RegionCode = 1")
```

**EDIT**

Sorry to answer my own, but I figured out how to do it and I wanted to leave this up in case someone else runs into this same issue.  The problem was with the WHERE arguments restricting the final output, instead of just the right hand table being fed into the join.  The code I used is below.

```
Species1<-sqldf("SELECT StartYear, StartMonthNo, RegionCode, CommonName, EstimatedBiomassg, ScaledProportionofDominantNektonBiomass
            FROM TrawlBiomassbyMonth
            WHERE CommonName='White shrimp'
            AND RegionCode=1")

Species1TimeSeries<-sqldf("SELECT TimeSeries.StartYear, TimeSeries.StartMonthNo, CommonName, EstimatedBiomassg, ScaledProportionofDominantNektonBiomass
            FROM TimeSeries
            LEFT JOIN Species1
            ON TimeSeries.StartYear = Species1.StartYear 
            AND TimeSeries.StartMonthNo = Species1.StartMonthNo")
```

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem! The policy on this site is that its ok to answer your own questions. In fact, in cases like this, it's _encouraged_. Please move your solution out of your question and into an answer. There's a mandatory waiting period, but after that you can accept it, which will help everyone see that this question has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following sql query?

```
SELECT TimeSeries.StartYear, TimeSeries.StartMonthNo, CommonName, EstimatedBiomassg, ScaledProportionofDominantNektonBiomass
        FROM TimeSeries 
        LEFT JOIN TrawlBiomassbyMonth 
        ON TimeSeries.StartYear = TrawlBiomassbyMonth.StartYear 
        AND TimeSeries.StartMonthNo = TrawlBiomassbyMonth.StartMonthNo 
        WHERE CommonName = 'White shrimp'
        AND RegionCode = 1")
```

From reading your post, the issue is there are some NULL fields in the right hand table, and you wish to include all rows from the left hand table even when there is no match?

Could you possibly setup a http://sqlfiddle.com/ ? PS due to my stackoverflow rep I was unable to comment, so although this isnt an answer, I'm trying to help

Comment: Your interpretation is correct, but the LEFT JOIN argument wasn't any more effective than the LEFT OUTER JOIN.  Thanks though.  I appreciate the help.